# How can I travel from Labuan Bajo to Lakey Peak?

Tags: transportation, indonesia

How can I get from Labuan Bajo, Indonesia to Lakey Peak, Indonesia?
I am in Labuan Bajo and I'm going to Lakey Peak. Which is cheapest: bus, car, ferry or plane?